# Representation of Dirac's delta function over a domain with periodic boundary condition

Tags: fourier-transform, distribution-theory, dirac-delta, quantum-mechanics

In my quantum mechanics notes, in connection to the problem of representing a function $\psi \in L^2(V)$ (where V is a cubic box centered at the origin, $V=\{ \bar{x}:|x_1|,|x_2|,|x_3| \leq L/2\})$ in the basis of plane waves: $\{\phi_k(\bar x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{L^3}}e^{i\bar{k}.\bar{x}},\bar{k}=\frac{2\pi}{L}(n_1,n_2,n_3),n_i \in \mathbb{Z}\}$, **they argue that the following is a representation of the Dirac's delta function:**
$$ \delta^3(\bar{y}-\bar{x})=\sum_{\bar{k}} \frac{e^{i\bar{k}.(\bar{y}-\bar{x})}}{L^3}$$

**Why is that true? Can someone give both a an intuitive/heuristic explanation and a rigorous one?**

They call the space $V$ I just defined a space with a periodic boundary condition, since $\phi_{\bar{k}}(x_1,x_2,x_3)=\phi_{\bar{k}}(x_1+L,x_2,x_3)=\phi_{\bar{k}}(x_1,x_2+L,x_3)=\phi_{\bar{k}}(x_1,x_2,x_3+L)$, so L is the period.

I know that in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ the dirac delta function can be represented with:
$$ \delta^3(\bar{y}-\bar{x})=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} d^3k \frac{e^{i\bar{k}.(\bar{y}-\bar{x})}}{(2\pi)^3}$$
but I am having trouble convincing myself of the statement in the limited cubic domain case  specialy because of that $\frac{1}{L^3}$ factor instead of the  $\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}$ which I fail to derive  logically from a Fourier transformation as they do here [Fourier Representation of Dirac's Delta Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3814073/fourier-representation-of-diracs-delta-function) for the $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ case

Can someone clear this up?

Comment: You can think of this as a product of three 1D cases, one for each direction. At that point, what you have is the [Dirac comb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_comb).

Comment: @Semiclassical  I am confused, a Dirac comb is an impulse train, even in one dimension and what I should get is a single delta not a bunch of them

Comment: A function with periodic boundary conditions over an interval is equivalent to a periodic function over the entire real line. As such, what you have _is_ a train of Dirac deltas. It's just that you're only studying one interval.

Comment: @Semiclassical  Oh, I see, but since the interval is closed [-L/2, L/2], wouldn't I have 3 deltas at 0, L/2 and -L/2? How do I get rid of the last two?

Comment: No. Your function is L-periodic, so there's also delta functions at $x=\pm L, \pm 2L$, etc. There's nothing strange going on at the $x=\pm L/2$ boundaries. Also, if you want to verify this for yourself, write down the Fourier expansion of your delta function as $\delta(x-y)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_k e^{i 2\pi x n/L}$ where $k_n=2\pi n/L$. Then multiply both sides by $e^{-i 2\pi x m/L}$ and integrate both sides over the domain of periodicity.

Comment: @Semiclassical So esentially the solution to my question is to 1) verify that the expresion for the Fourier series of the Dirac comb, which i found here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_comb,2)  then change variables to have the sum over k instead of n and 3)go to 3 dimensions. Right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118397/discussion-between-semiclassical-and-mathlover).